# Python. Raise exception from multiple exceptions

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, error-handling, raise

I can raise an exception `from` another exception in order to provide additional information, e.g.:

```
try:
    age = int(x)
except Exception as ex:
    raise ValueError("{} is not a valid age.".format(x)) from ex
```

Is there any way to source from **multiple** exceptions? e.g.

```
try:
    age = int(x)
except Exception as ex1:
    try:
        age = date_now().year - parse_date(x).year
    except Exception as ex2:
        raise ValueError("{} is not a valid age or date.".format(x)) from ex1 + ex2
```

Comment: why do you want to create multiple exceptions, you can create user defined exceptions and raise them based on the logic

Comment: @Kalyan exactly. You should keep your logic in `try/except` and raise different exceptions from there, if there is a need for them.

Comment: I don't want to create multiple exceptions, I want multiple exceptions in the trace. "**source** from multiple".

Answer (score 0):

An earlier exception that causes an exception currently being handled is stored in the `__context__` attribute of the current exception object, while the exception explicitly specified in the `from` of the `raise` statement is stored as the `__cause__` attribute, per the specifications of [PEP 344 – Exception Chaining and Embedded Tracebacks](https://peps.python.org/pep-0344/):

> For an explicitly chained exception, this PEP suggests `__cause__`
> because of its specific meaning. For an implicitly chained exception,
> this PEP proposes the name `__context__` because the intended meaning is
> more specific than temporal precedence but less specific than
> causation: an exception occurs in the context of handling another
> exception.

Both `__cause__` and `__context__` are formatted properly in the traceback report, so the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime
 
x = 'foo'
try:
    age = int(x)
except ValueError:
    try:
        age = datetime.now().year - datetime.fromisoformat(x).year
    except ValueError as e:
        raise ValueError(f'{x} is not a valid age or date.') from e
```

would produce the following traceback with all the exception sources properly noted:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 5, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'foo'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 8, in <module>
ValueError: Invalid isoformat string: 'foo'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 10, in <module>
ValueError: foo is not a valid age or date.
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/icdd8K